# Compare analytical and numerical Sine Transform

Tags: fourier-transform, wolfram-alpha

According to the [FFTW Website](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/1d-Real_002dodd-DFTs-_0028DSTs_0029.html#g_t1d-Real_002dodd-DFTs-_0028DSTs_0029), the Fourier Sine Transform (FST) returns:

$$Y_k = 2 \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} X_i \sin [\pi (j+1)(k+1)/(N+1)]$$

[WolframAlpha](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierSinTransform.html) defines the Fourier Sine Transform as follows:
$2\sqrt\frac{\lvert b \rvert}{(2\pi)^{1-a}} \int_0^\infty f(t)\sin(b\omega t)\mathrm{d}t$

Taking $a=1$ and $b=\pi$ this becomes: 
$F^{W}_{sin} = 2\sqrt \pi \int_0^\infty f(t)\sin(b\omega t)\mathrm{d}t$.

Comparing the two definitions one can write:

$$Y_k = 2 \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} X_i \sin [\pi (j+1)(k+1)/(N+1)] \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt\pi} F^{W}_{s}$$

Setting $f(t) = t\mathrm{e}^{-t^2}$ and performing FourierSinTransform, Wolframalpha returns:

$$FST\{f(t)\}= \frac{1}{2}\pi^2\omega\mathrm{e}^{-(1/4)\pi^2\omega^2}$$

I implemented this in my code and I was puzzled by the results: The analytical and numerical solutions look 
similar but I would have expected a higher precision. What is the reason for this? Am I doing some error in 
reasoning?

Any help is appreciated.

```
// RosenbluthFourier.cpp : Definiert den Einstiegspunkt für die Konsolenanwendung.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fftw3.h>



int main() {

int const Pi = 3.14159265359;
int N;
double sup;

cout << "enter N of points "; std::cin >> N;
cout << "enter sup "; std::cin >> sup;
cout << "Interval runs from 0 to " << sup << " and will be divided into " << N
    << " intervals." << endl;

double T, Df;
T = sup / (N-1);
Df = 1 / sup;
cout << "Sampling interval T = " << T << endl;
cout << "Frequency spacing df = " << Df << endl << endl; 

double *X = new double[N];
double *Y = new double[N];

for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
    X[i] = T*i;
    Y[i] = X[i] * exp(-pow(X[i],2));
    cout << "X[" << i << "] = " << X[i] << "  Y[" << i << "] = " << Y[i] << endl;
}

cout << endl << "Analitically tranformed function" << endl << endl ;

double *f = new double[N];
double *Yt = new double[N];

for (int k = 0; k <= N; k++) {
    // calc pi*w
    f[k] = Pi*k*Df;
    Yt[k] = (1./2.)*Pi*f[k] * exp(-pow(f[k]/2., 2));
    cout << "f[" << k << "] = " << f[k] << "  Yt[" << k << "] = " << Yt[k] << endl;
}

cout << endl << "FFTW-tranformed function" << endl << endl;

fftw_plan p;
p = fftw_plan_r2r_1d(N, Y, Yt, FFTW_RODFT00, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute(p);

for (int k = 0; k <= N; k++) {
    Yt[k] = Yt[k] * T * double(sqrt(Pi)) ;
    cout << "f[" << k << "] = " << f[k] << "  Yt[" << k << "] = " << Yt[k] << endl;
}

fftw_destroy_plan(p);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int const Pi = 3.14159265359;
```

The above is equivalent to `int const Pi = 3;` as far as C++ is concerned, which is not a good choice when you care about precision.

Try the following, instead, which also adds more decimals, since the `double` type has about 16 significant digits (at least if the implementation is IEEE-754 compliant):

```
double const Pi = 3.14159265358979324;
```

---

[ *EDIT* ]     `for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {`

The above wil run the loop $N+1$ times due to the `<=` inclusive comparison. But the arrays are only allocated for $N$ elements `double *X = new double[N];` so the last iteration invokes undefined behavior (out-of-bounds write). Everything that happens from that point on is technically undefined by the language standards. In practice, the code is corrupting some random memory locations which may, or may not, affect the end results.

Comment: That was a really bad mistake shame on me! Still something is not convincing me. Would you mind to take a look at the plot and eventually at the data files?

Comment: @DaniloLE I added one more point to the answer. That said, you may have better luck with the code side of it next door at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Just be sure to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The FourierSineTransform was performed with 64 points in the interval [0,5]

[Analytical and numerical FST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqes5.png)

Comment: This is relevant information, but it belongs into the question itself (which you can always edit). It's not an answer and shouldn't be posted as one.